# How can I get rid of the resize-handle in a QDialog?

Tags: qt, pyqt

I've got the following class:

```
class SelectDateDialog(QDialog):
    startDate = date.today()
    endDate = date.today()

    def __init__(self, text, isInterval = False):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("resources/SelectDate.ui", self)
```

Now, the dialog is resizable on Mac OS X 10.5, but it shouldn't be. It has the resize-handle in the lower right corner.

I've already tried the `setSizeGripEnabled` function, it didn't change anything.

How can I make it not resizable?

Comment: Why would you want to prevent the dialog from being resizable? I can't think of a case where fixed size would be better than resizable, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: It's the kind of dialog that just states a message. This looks way better and feels more like an Mac OS X program. QMessageBox does it right.

Answer (score 8):

if you want a non-resizable QDialog dlg, 
then set

```
dlg.setWindowFlags(Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint);
```

Answer (score 5):

I use the following code to fix the size of a `QDialog`:

```
layout()->setSizeConstraint( QLayout::SetFixedSize ) ;
setSizeGripEnabled( false ) ;
```

The first line enforces the layout size based on the preferred size of the widgets contained within the layout. The second line removes the actual grip.

To reverse this, you would set the default constraint on the layout and re-enable the size grip.

Answer (score 4):

The cleanest way to make a window or dialog non-resizable is to set the size constraint of its layout to QLayout.SetFixedSize (or QLayout::SetFixedSize in C++). You only need to do this for the main layout in the window - the one which contains all the other widgets and layouts.

I see that you're using Qt Designer to create the user interface for your dialog. Open the .ui file and select the window, then scroll down in the property editor until you see the Layout section. Set the layoutSizeConstraint property to SetFixedSize.

When you preview the form, the widgets inside the dialog should be arranged correctly, but you won't be able to resize the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, I have always had to do the following (in Qt Designer) to be absolutely sure the window could not be resized:

```
sizePolicy -> Horizontal Policy = Fixed
sizePolicy -> Vertical Policy = Fixed

minimumSize -> Width = X
minimumSize -> Height = Y

maximumSize -> Width = X
maximumSize -> Height = Y
```

Note that I chose X and Y to illustrate that **minimumSize == maximumSize**. When you do this, the resize handle *should* disappear on its own, though I have seen at least one distribution of Linux leave the handle on. In that particular case, we just hid the handle, since it could not resize the window anyway.