# Qt tool window resizable on Mac

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, macos, qwidget

I have a Qt window with the following flags:

```
Qt::CustomizeWindowHint
|Qt::Tool
|Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint
|Qt::WindowTitleHint
|Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint
```

On Mac, it has a resizable corner. How can I get rid of it? Specifying

```
setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed));
```

does not help. In fact, with the fixed-size policy the window acts weird when I try to resize - it disappears from foreground and becomes disabled for some reason.

I don't mind dropping to the native API level.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get rid of the resize-handle in a QDialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575294/how-can-i-get-rid-of-the-resize-handle-in-a-qdialog)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in [the Qt FAQ](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/faq/answer/how_can_i_get_rid_of_the_sizegrip_of_a_window_on_mac_os_x).